# Can't login via php curl

Tags: php, curl, authentication

I wanna login to   [out university food reservation](http://stu24.kntu.ac.ir) so edit  `action` of form in Google Chrome and send data to my website to see what has been sent when I press submit button.

```
__LASTFOCUS=&__EVENTTARGET=&__EVENTARGUMENT=&__VIEWSTATE=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&__EVENTVALIDATION=/wEWBALtyp+2DQKl1bKdCAK1qbT2CQKC3IfLCT5A0UwjzwbH6JTK21okH7qC0C74&txtusername=myusername&txtpassword=mypassword&btnlogin=ورود&
```

after that I develop e code with php and curl to do it automatically.

```
$post_fields = '__LASTFOCUS=&__EVENTTARGET=&__EVENTARGUMENT=&__VIEWSTATE=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&__EVENTVALIDATION=/wEWBALtyp+2DQKl1bKdCAK1qbT2CQKC3IfLCT5A0UwjzwbH6JTK21okH7qC0C74&txtusername=8909103&txtpassword=temptemp&btnlogin=ورود&';
    $ch = curl_init("http://stu24.kntu.ac.ir/Login.aspx");;
    $cookie = fopen("temp.txt", "w+");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION,1);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie); 
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.9.0.8) Gecko/2009032609 Firefox/3.0.8');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_fields);
    $x = curl_exec($ch);
    echo ($x);
    curl_close($ch);
```

but it will return error from the server.

```
Server Error in '/' Application.

The state information is invalid for this page and might be corrupted.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.Web.HttpException: The state information is invalid for this page and might be corrupted.

Source Error: 

The source code that generated this unhandled exception can only be shown when compiled in debug mode. To enable this, please follow one of the below steps, then request the URL:

1. Add a "Debug=true" directive at the top of the file that generated the error. Example:

  

or:

2) Add the following section to the configuration file of your application:


   
       
   


Note that this second technique will cause all files within a given application to be compiled in debug mode. The first technique will cause only that particular file to be compiled in debug mode.

Important: Running applications in debug mode does incur a memory/performance overhead. You should make sure that an application has debugging disabled before deploying into production scenario.

Stack Trace: 


[FormatException: Invalid length for a Base-64 char array.]
   System.Convert.FromBase64String(String s) +0
   System.Web.UI.ObjectStateFormatter.Deserialize(String inputString) +72
   System.Web.UI.ObjectStateFormatter.System.Web.UI.IStateFormatter.Deserialize(String serializedState) +4
   System.Web.UI.Util.DeserializeWithAssert(IStateFormatter formatter, String serializedState) +37
   System.Web.UI.HiddenFieldPageStatePersister.Load() +113

[ViewStateException: Invalid viewstate. 
    Client IP: 209.54.48.51
    Port: 47212
    User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.9.0.8) Gecko/2009032609 Firefox/3.0.8
    ViewState: 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...]

[HttpException (0x80004005): The state information is invalid for this page and might be corrupted.]
   System.Web.UI.ViewStateException.ThrowError(Exception inner, String persistedState, String errorPageMessage, Boolean macValidationError) +106
   System.Web.UI.ViewStateException.ThrowViewStateError(Exception inner, String persistedState) +14
   System.Web.UI.HiddenFieldPageStatePersister.Load() +217
   System.Web.UI.Page.LoadPageStateFromPersistenceMedium() +105
   System.Web.UI.Page.LoadAllState() +43
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +6785
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +242
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest() +80
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestWithNoAssert(HttpContext context) +21
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) +49
   ASP.login_aspx.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) +37
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +181
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +75

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:2.0.50727.3053; ASP.NET Version:2.0.50727.3053
```

and if I do limit `$post_fields` to only username and password,it will redirect to login page again.
where is the problem and how should I solve it?

Answer (score 0):

You have invalid viewstate. Try to `urlencode` your `$post_fields` If that doesn't help try to first visit login -page and get viestate from there ?